# Add video track while navigator.getUserMedia in running

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to use navigator.getUserMedia() api for capturing the audio/video. I've following code.

```
var cameraEl;

    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia);
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        { video: true, audio: true },
        function (stream) {

            cameraEl = document.getElementById("selfCam");
            cameraEl.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            window.mediaStream = stream;

        },
        function () {
            alert('Error: Camera failed!');
        }
    );
```

Than I stop the video track like this,

```
window.mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

Now I want to start the video track again. How do I start it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call getUserMedia again. stop() is a final action.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. But is there any feature with which I can pause the video track and resume it later, instead of stopping the video track.

Comment: the easiest way is to disable the videotrack by doing this:

    `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;`
This sends black frames until you set enabled to true again. This does not release the camera and the light stays on.
Renegotiation, i.e. removing the track from the stream and later adding it again is supported in browsers these days but rather tedious.